# Error connecting Power Apps to SQL Server using Azure AD Integrated authentication (The server is not currently configured to accept this token)

Tags: sql-server, authentication, azure-active-directory, powerapps

I have 2 tenants: Tenant 1 (@tenant1.org) and Tenant 2 (@tenant2.org). I have a Azure AD group (Group1) in Tenant 1 which has all users in Tenant 1. All users in Tenant 2 are added as guests in the AD group (Group1) in Tenant 1. All the members in Group1 (both from Tenant 1 and Tenant 2) can all access a Power Apps canvas application that is created in Tenant 1 and shared with Group1. The canvas application accesses data in SQL Server using a SQL Server connector that is using Azure AD Integrated authentication. The database has the user Group1 added and granted both read and write permissions. Users in Tenant 1 access the data via the application with no errors but users in Tenant 2 get the following error when accessing data via the application "error when trying to retrieve data from the network: Login failed for user . The server is not currently configured to accept this token". Can anyone guide me on how to go about solving this.

I tried granting the users access both via group membership and directly as users but the errors remain the same. I was expecting all the users to connect successfully to the SQL Server database from the Power Apps application

Comment: Check if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/133709/login-failed-for-user

Comment: @Sridevi, thanks for the link. I had tried that with a few users but the behavior/ error remains the same whether I grant access via individual contained database users or via the group membership.